# Skip specific code from a Specific point in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I skip specific code from a Specific point in c#? 
Suppose within an if condition I am using another if condition and I want to skip that, than how can I skip that lower code if inner if condition goes false. then how can I achieve that?
this is my scenario

```
if(true)
{
    var discount = GetDicsount(price);
    if(discount > 100)
    {
        //kill here and go away to from main if condition and skip do other work and move to GetType line directly
    }
    //Do Other Work
}
int type = GetType(20);
```

Comment: That´s exactly what the if is doing. If the condition does not meet the code will no execute.

Comment: Use `return` in inner if like `if(discount > 100){ return; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could invert `if`

```
if (discount <= 100) {
   // Do Other Work
}
```

There is no command which would break from the `if` block,
but you could use `goto` but that makes your code harder to follow.

**I think the real problem here is not-so-good nesting.**

Take a look at the nesting problems and how to flatten your code
so it becomes more readable and easier to follow:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Coding_Style/Minimize_nesting
http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern

So your code could look this, for example:

```
var discount = (int?) null;
if (someCondition)
{
    discount = GetDiscount(price);
}

if (discount.Value <= 100)
{
    // Do Other Work
}

int type = GetType(20);
```

Comment: Yes right answer was using the goto statement.thanks

Comment: @AliNafees - Using GOTO statements is **rarely** if ever the right answer.  The correct answer is to flatten your nested if statements as this reduces code complexity, makes your code extremely more readable and reduces the overall number of branches that you would need to test.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change your logic so that you reverse the if logic and do other work in there?

```
if(true){
   var discount = GetDiscount(price);
  if(discount <= 100){
   //Do Other Work
  }
}
int type = GetType(20);
```

Note that your outer if statement is always true. I'm assuming that's just for the example, but if it's actual code you can remove it:

```
var discount = GetDiscount(price);
if(discount > 100)
{
    return;
}
//Do Other Work
```

If you really want to do what you asked, you could look at [goto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) (not recommended).

```
if(true)
{
    var discount = GetDiscount(price);
    if(discount > 100)
    {
        goto last;
    }
    //Do Other Work
}
last:
int type = GetType(20);
```

Comment: Yes We can do it in that way  but is there a way to do that like I have asked?

Comment: @AliNafees updated. You could use goto. This is really bad design though.